# Google Sheets Function to get value of adjacent cell based on key

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help figuring out some Google Sheets function. I'm trying to look for the value of an adjacent cell based on a key. The problem is that the table has several rows and columns to search for. For example:

```
  |    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
1 | Alpha   | 5       | Bravo   | 10      |
2 | Charlie | 15      | Delta   | 20      |
```

The list goes on for several more rows and colums. What I'm looking for for example, is when a search use "Delta" as my search key, it will return the value 20 for me. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Did either of the formulas below work for you?  If so please mark the one that worked as correct.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark the question as answered.  If they did not work, some feedback will help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer I got on the web application community:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90198/how-to-get-value-of-adjacent-cell-based-on-key-if-the-table-is-split-into-multi

> You can still use `vlookup` for this, by stacking the lookup tables into one using the array notation {first ; second; third} which means first above second above third. Example:
>
> ```
> =vlookup("Delta", {A:B; C:D}, 2, False)
> ```
>
> returns 20.

Comment: I did something similar, but composed the lookup table slightly differently by stacking columns A and C together, and making a second column by stacking B and D together: =VLOOKUP(F3, {{A:A;C:C},{B:B;D:D}}, 2, false)
I think the one above is cleaner, though, because it stacks "A:B" directly on top of "C:D".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=offset(lookup("Delta",A1:D2),0,1)
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because using your formula I get the correct answer for Delta, but the wrong for the other three.

Comment: This won't work, because LOOKUP requires data to be sorted. See @franco's answer above for a good solution using VLOOKUP instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX($A$1:$D$2,MIN(IF($A$1:$D$2=$G$1,ROW($A$1:$D$2))),MIN(IF($A$1:$D$2=$G$1,COLUMN($A$1:$D$2)))+1))
```

[image]

Comment: Far too unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score -1):

This could by done in several ways.

**Use RegEx**

```
=regexextract(CONCATENATE(A1:D),F6 & "(\d+)")
```

where F6 is cell with lookup value i.e. "Delta"

**Use lookup**

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(LOOKUP(F6,A1:D,A1:A),A1:A),MATCH(F6,INDIRECT(MATCH(LOOKUP(F6,A1:D,A1:A),A1:A)&":"&MATCH(LOOKUP(F6,A1:D,A1:A),A1:A)))+1)
```

where F6 is cell with lookup value i.e. "Delta", [look at example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r--g7OoD_m5R0o3zwSQue9eUDXOLSBTyCe9M0yvEFUo/edit?usp=sharing).

`MATCH(LOOKUP(F6,A1:D,A1:A),A1:A)` is used 3 times, so it could be counted in separate cell.